# Can the Google Sheets QUERY function return a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

When using the QUERY function in Google Sheets, is there a way to return a formula in the result? It seems that if I query a cell containing a formula, I only get the value of that formula. Is there a way to preserve the formula so it works in the queried copy?

Comment: .............No

Comment: Can you give an example of a work (preferably a spreadsheet) what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

No It's Returns Data Only. It is Just Link SQL Queries.